# Await keyword not waiting for promise to be fulfilled in NodeJS with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm new to javascript and async functions, and I'm trying to write an API in NodeJs with Express that takes a JPG image from Postman and puts it into my image classification machine learning model (that was adapted from MobileNet) for predictions. The image needs to be preprocessed before it can be put through the model. I use the packages resize-optimize-images get-image-data to resize and change the image into an appropriate format for my model.

```
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const image = require('get-image-data');
const resizeOptimizeImages = require('resize-optimize-images');

let model;
(async function () {
    model = await tf.loadLayersModel("http://localhost:5000/model/model.json");
})();

app.post('/classify', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    
        //call methods to resize and preprocess the image
        resize();
        var input =  preprocess();

        //have model predict
        console.log(input);
        let prediction = model.predict(input);
});
```

Here is my code for the resize function.

```
function resize() {
    (async () => {
        // Set the options.
        const options = {
            images: [imagePath],
            width: 224,
            height: 224,
            quality: 90
        };
        
        // Run the module.
        await resizeOptimizeImages(options);
        console.log("resized");
        
    })();
}
```

Here is my code for the preprocess function.

```
function preprocess() {

    image(imagePath, async (err, imageData) => {

        // pre-process image
        const numChannels = 3;
        const numPixels = imageData.width * imageData.height;
        const values = new Int32Array(numPixels * numChannels);
        const pixels = imageData.data;

        for (let i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
            for (let channel = 0; channel < numChannels; ++channel) {
                values[i * numChannels + channel] = pixels[i * 4 + channel];
            }
        }
        const outShape = [imageData.height, imageData.width, numChannels];
        const input = tf.tensor3d(values, outShape, 'float32');
        console.log(input);
        return input;

    });
```

When I run the program, I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" at the line where I'm calling predict. The functions resize and preprocess are not fully carried out, resulting in the input to predict being undefined. I thought that by putting await by resizeImageOptimizer(), the program would wait for that process to be fulfilled before moving on. However, it appears to be doing this at the very end, even though it is called first.
Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The IIFE that contains `model = await tf.loadLayersModel(...)` is not running asychronously and you're not awaiting it. So it doesn't wait for it.

Comment: Putting an async function in an IIFE doesn't make the containing code wait for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so try to use async await like this

```
const resize = async () => {
    const options = {
        images: [imagePath],
        width: 224,
        height: 224,
        quality: 90
    };
    
    // Run the module.
    await resizeOptimizeImages(options);
    console.log("resized");
 }
```

Also here you must pass async function as well:

```
app.post('/classify', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

    //call methods to resize and preprocess the image
    await resize();
    var input = await preprocess();

    //have model predict
    console.log(input);
    let prediction = model.predict(input)
})
```

Keep in mind that async/await only works with Promises, so your functions like `preprocess()` must also return Promise:

```
const preprocess = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
    image(imagePath, (err, imageData) => {

    // pre-process image
    const numChannels = 3;
    const numPixels = imageData.width * imageData.height;
    const values = new Int32Array(numPixels * numChannels);
    const pixels = imageData.data;

    for (let i = 0; i < numPixels; i++) {
        for (let channel = 0; channel < numChannels; ++channel) {
            values[i * numChannels + channel] = pixels[i * 4 + channel];
        }
    }
    const outShape = [imageData.height, imageData.width, numChannels];
    const input = tf.tensor3d(values, outShape, 'float32');
    console.log(input);
    resolve(input);

});
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put inside arrow function, just make the main function `async`, also make `option` object in `let` because `const` is used for constant values, but you are providing dynamic `imagepath`

```
async function resize() {
    // Set the options.
    let options = {
      images: [imagePath],
      width: 224,
      height: 224,
      quality: 90
    };
        
    // Run the module.
    await resizeOptimizeImages(options);
    console.log("resized");

}
```

Also, you can put `async await` in the route as well, but that's optional:

```
app.post('/classify', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    
        //call methods to resize and preprocess the image
        let resize = await resize();
        var input =  preprocess();

        //have model predict
        console.log(input);
        let prediction = model.predict(input);
});
```